# Adding Contents to JFrame Before Setting Visible

Tags: java, swing, object, visibility

I have a JFrame that I create in the main function. I want to add a JTextField to it. The problem I'm having is that the JFrame is created and then - with about a second delay - the JTextField is added. Is there a way I can draw the text field to my window and then show all at once? Thanks in advance!

For reference, here is my code:

```
public class Window {

public static final JFrame window = new JFrame();
public static final JTextField input = new JTextField();

private static void loadWindow(){

    window.setSize(800, 600);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    input.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 60));

    window.add(input);
    window.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    loadWindow();

}

}
```

Here's the timeline of what's happening:

First second:

[image]

Second after:

[image]

Comment: No part in this snippet is pointing to the fact, that some delay is occurring. Though if you are trying to add controls to a `JFrame` or to an already visible `JFrame`, then try `frame.pack()` after adding component, that will suffice, IMHO.

Comment: The JFrame is not visible, it is exactly as shown in the example. I don't know why this delay is occurring. I am using Mac OSX and the JFrame is visible before the text field is.

Comment: Where is this `JTextField` in question initialized? Are you running the Swing's code on `Event Dispatcher Thread-EDT` and not from main thread?

Comment: Please take a look at the edit.

Comment: Are you running the Swing's code on `Event Dispatcher Thread-EDT` and not from main thread? If `frame.setVisible(true)` is the last call, then, I have never seen such a thingy before, a small runnable example will be quite helpful :-)

Comment: Have you run the debugger? How big is your program?

Comment: It is very small and indeed very weird. I have run the debugger and everything seems normal.

Comment: Could you post all of the code so I can recreate it? Also, which version of Java are you running?

Comment: where is the loadWindow() method being called from.

Comment: Please take a look at the edit.

Comment: Try instantiating the JFrame and JTextField within the loadWindow() method. i.e calling new ..() on them rather than in the class. Also not so sure why these would be final.

Comment: I have previously tried this and it was the same result so I reverted back to this version.

Comment: Which IDE and version are you using? Which version of Java are you running? How are you calling the application?

Comment: I am using the latest version of NetBeans and the latest Java SDK. I am calling the application from the IDE.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but shouldn't you set the size of the text field directly instead of setting its preferred size.

Comment: Thank you! Removing that line did the trick! However, my text field has no size now.

Comment: Really... I was not able to reproduce the error with the code you posted.

Comment: Do setSize() to set the size of the textfield

Comment: It may be an OS related problem. I have tried the same code several times and always had this error.

Comment: try updateUI();/window.revalidate(); window.setVisible(true);

Comment: The current code works fine for me. The only time it lags the appearance of `JTextField` was the first time and I guess it had to do with the compilation. How long is the delay? Is it systematic?

Comment: It is always about one second.

Comment: If you don't run Swing on EDT, you cannot expect it to work. Wrap your `loadWindow()` call in [SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29). Also, instead of what you are doing now, extend a JFrame and instantiate that. No need for static swing components...

Comment: I did note, during my testing, that the field seems to become visible when the cursor is first painted, hence the second (or so) delay

Comment: Instead of `public static final JTextField input = new JTextField(); .. input.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 60));` set a large font for the height and use `new JTextField(20);` for the width.  Then add it to a panel with a large `EmtpyBorder`. Then add that panel to the frame and call `pack()`.  **Do it all on the EDT.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chalk this one to weirdness...

I changed

```
public static final JTextField input = new JTextField();
```

to

```
public static final JTextField input = new JTextField(20);
```

And it worked fine...

I would however encourage you...

- to avoid using `setPreferredSize` as it won't always work on every platform as you don't control the rendering pipelines which can affect the amount of space a component will need in order to render properly
- Start your UI's in the EDT...

For example...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        loadWindow();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you would want the JFrame and JTextField to have the final access modifiers.
[How final keyword works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-final-keyword-works)
Try removing these.

Comment: This does not fix the issue.

Comment: Finally simply renters that the value can't be reassigned

Answer (score -1):

Use setSize() to configure the size of Components. setPreferrredSize() will be applied at an unknown time or whenever you call pack on the component.

Comment: Once the window is realised, the layout manager will be called to perform a layout, discarding any changes you made with `setSize`

Comment: Your right. I tend to use null for the layout. That's where setSize() will do the trick.

Comment: *"I tend to use null for the layout."*  -1.  Please stop making comments on Java GUI construction until you discover the pitfalls of `null` layouts.