# Why does adding final bytes result in a byte but adding non-final bytes results in an int?

Tags: java, jvm, final

```
byte b1=1,b2=2,b3,b6; 
final byte b4=4,b5=6; 
b6=b4+b5;    // line3
b3=b1+b2;    // line4: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
System.out.println(b3+b6);
```

Why line 3 is right? It seems the type is not correct and I should be getting the error I get on line 4.

[Live example on ideone](http://ideone.com/KFhxLU)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How final keyword works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-final-keyword-works)

Comment: What compiler error message are you getting? Usually those contain helpful information.

Comment: Presumably since `b4` and `b5` are `final`, the compiler knows that they are in a suitable range to add into a `byte` variable...?

Comment: Please review the edits I've made to your question. Always include the actual error message and avoid irrelevant differences when comparing two lines (the `()`). Half-decent variable names would have helped a lot, too. It's a really interesting question, but the way it was asked lead to it being downvoted.

Comment: @PatrickCollins - definitely not a duplicate of [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15655012/1945631).

Comment: @AndyBrown You're right, I assumed he was getting a generic "can't reassign a final variable", with the error message in I see that it was something surprising. Retracted.

Answer (score 8):

The error occurs on line 4 and not line 3 because the **compiler** knows the values of the `final` variables, but doesn't know the values of the non-`final` variables. The compiler sees `final` and that the variable is definitely assigned prior to use with a constant value, and as the variable is `final`, that value cannot be changed. Since the compiler knows the values, it knows that there is no loss in the conversion of the value 10 (`b4+b5`). In fact, they're effectively constants and you're doing `b6=10` — and if you look at the bytecode generated if we remove line 4 and adjust line 6, we see that that's exactly what the compiler does: Optimizes `b4` and `b5` away entirely.

If you chose different values for `b4` and `b5` (`100`, for instance), you'd get an error on line 3 as well:

```
byte b1=1,b2=2,b3,b6; 
final byte b4=100,b5=100; 
b6=b4+b5;  // line3 error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
b3=b1+b2;  // line4 error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
System.out.println(b3+b6);
```

[Live on ideone](http://ideone.com/BkSqwU)

Here's something demonstrating this, that will compile

```
byte b1=1,b2=2,b3,b6; 
final byte b4=4,b5=6; 
b6=b4+b5;  // line3
//b3=b1+b2;  // line4
//System.out.println(b3+b6);
System.out.println(b6);
```

And here's the disassembly:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]) throws java.lang.Exception;
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: iconst_2
       3: istore_2
       4: bipush        10
       6: istore        4
       8: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      11: iload         4
      13: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      16: return
```

Note the

```
4: bipush        10
6: istore        4
```

...which is storing the literal value 10 in `b6`.

Answer (score -1):

> How does JVM process keyword “final” ?
>   JVM in runtime doesn't know about this modifier. Compilator does.

Your issue isn't about final, to eliminate error do this:

```
b3=(byte)(b1+b2);   // line isn't invalid now
```

One time assignment to a final variable defined earlier is a valid statement itself.

Line 3 - compiler just inline your values as integer constant.

```
   L4
    LINENUMBER 30 L4
    BIPUSH 10
    ISTORE 4
```

Line 4 - compiler can't do this.

```
   L5
    LINENUMBER 31 L5
    ILOAD 1
    ILOAD 2
    IADD
    I2B
    ISTORE 3
```

Read next:
http://www.javatpoint.com/final-keyword

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Why does he need that for line 4 and not for line 3?

Comment: This depends. Actually, need for line 3 too, but compiler do your work inlining the final values and conclude that there isn't overflow.