# Can I initialize final variables by calling the class methods?

Tags: java

I am writing a java program, that needs some final variables. The java class must be a singleton object. And I can't directly initialize the final variable. Here is my code:

```
 public class Car {

    private Price price = null;

    //Constructor
    public Car(Price p) {
       this.price = p;
    }

    //method to get the singleton
    private static Car instance = null;       
    public static Car getInstance(Price p) {
       if(instance == null) {
          instance = new ExcelUtil2(p);
       }
       return instance;
    }

    //declare & initialize final variable
    private final Wheel WHEEL_TYPE = getWheelType();

    //get value of the final variable
    public Wheel getWheelType() {

        Wheel wheel = Car.createWheel();

        if(price.getAmount() > 30000){
            wheel.setWheelType("Alloy");
        }else{
            wheel.setWheelType("Alluminium");
        }

        return wheel;
    }
}
```

And I would like to know whether if I can do like this or not:

```
private final Wheel WHEEL_TYPE = getWheelType();
```

That is my first question.

And the next thing is, when I run it I am getting nullPointerException at:

```
price.getAmount()
```

in `public Wheel getWheelType()` method.

I am initializing price using a public constructor.

I am initilizing the class in some other class like this:

```
Car car = Car.getInstance(price);
```

Here I verified that both the price object and price.getAmount() are not null.

Can anyone guide me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Well what happened when you tried it?

Comment: You might want to think about when the field initializers are executed vs when the `this.price = p;` statement in your constructor body gets called...

Comment: "WHEEL_TYPE = getWheelType();' should work. You can also not initialize 'wheel' at declaration (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Blank_final) and do the initialization in the constructor.

Comment: You can do: private final Wheel WHEEL_TYPE = getWheelType();

Comment: @resueman Please see my edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with

```
private final Wheel WHEEL_TYPE = getWheelType();
```

In general, though, (as recommended in [the Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)), when you do that you should be calling method that cannot be overridden—a `final` method, a `static` method, a `private` method, or a method in a `final` class.

However, with your particular code there is a problem. In the execution of `getWheelType()`, you are calling `price.getAmount()` and `price` gets initialized in the body of the constructor. Unfortunately for your design, field instance initializers are executed before the body of the constructor, so you will end up calling `price.getAmount()` before `price` is initialized.

I recommend that you simply move the assignment to `WHEEL_TYPE` to inside the constructor, after the assignment to `price`.

Comment: If I move the assignment to inside the constructor then I can't make the variable final, right?

Comment: @TheGuest - Sure you can. `final` fields can be assigned (once) in a constructor. If you have several constructors, each must ensure that the field is assigned exactly once, either in the body of the constructor or by calling another constructor.

Comment: And I would like to know if this is a bad design or ok to follow. Because my project is purely standalone java project (no spring, no ejb, no struts, no jdbc and etc; only java)

Comment: @TheGuest - It's very common, and perfectly fine design, to move complex initialization logic out of the constructor and into a helper method like that. The only issue is that the compiler will not trace such calls to ensure that `final` methods are definitely assigned exactly once; the assignments _must_ be done where the compiler expects them: in the constructor(s), in instance initializers, or in instance initializer blocks.

Answer (score 1):

> You are always allowed to initialize a final variable. The compiler
>   makes sure that you can do it only once.

Excerpt from an answer here: [How final keyword works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-final-keyword-works?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

As Ed mentioned, your price is an instance variable and it is used inside the instance method getWheelType(), which is OK. But the problem is this method is used to create a final variable.  The final variable is assigned before the instance variable p is assigned.

If you really want to have your code structure, you may consider using a Builder pattern.  My code is not well considered, but it will be something like this.

```
public class CarTwo {
   private Price price = null;
   private Builder b;
   public Builder getBuilder(){
      return b;
   }

   private final Wheel WHEEL_TYPE;

   private CarTwo(Builder b) {
      this.b = b;
      this.price = b.getPrice();
      WHEEL_TYPE = b.getWheelType();
   }

   private static CarTwo instance = null;       
   public static CarTwo getInstance(Builder builder) {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ExcelUtil2(builder);
      }
      return instance;
   }

   public static class Builder{
     private Price pr;
     public Builder(Price price){
        pr = price;
     }

     public Price getPrice(){
        return pr;
     }
     public Wheel getWheelType() {
        Wheel wheel = CarTwo.createWheel();

        if(pr.getAmount() > 30000){
           wheel.setWheelType("Alloy");
        }else{
           wheel.setWheelType("Alluminium");
        }

        return wheel;
     }
  }
}
```

Then, you can create the CarTwo object like this:

```
CarTwo.Builder b = new CarTwo.Builder(new Price());  
CarTwo ct = CarTwo.getInstance(b);
```