# How to link 2 final arrays

Tags: java

So I'm having trouble finding out how to link 2 final arrays. Something like this:

```
    final String[] array1 = new String[4];
    final String[] array2 = new String[4];

    array1 = array2;
```

But because both arrays are final, I can't do what I've done in the example above. Is there any way I can set array1 to array2, so that any changes made to array1 will be reflected into array2 automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have two dedicated arrays in the first place? And since they are final you can only try some nasty reflection stuff.

Comment: Also, even if the arrays weren't final,  when doing array1 = array 2, you lose the reference to array1 and all its content with it.

Comment: the 2 references are final so can't do this

Comment: Why not remove the `final` modifier?. Are you pasing this to some anonymous class?

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-final-keyword-works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can set array1 to array2, so that any changes made to array1 will be reflected into array2 automatically?

Automatically, not. Once you've initialized `array1` and `array2` with something, you can't re-initialize them again, since they're both `final`.

However, you could manually *copy* `array2`'s content to `array1`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    array1[i] = array2[i];
}
```

This will work, because the `final` modified doesn't guarantee immutability - it just makes sure that once the reference to a variable is set, it cannot change anymore.

Comment: What I was trying to do was more complex than my example, I was just trying to show what I was trying to do but thanks to the help of you all I've managed to understand what I'm doing wrong now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If we want the changes of array1 reflected in array2 then we don't need to declare two different arrays. We can just point array2's reference to array1 and it will show the changes e.g.:

```
final String[] array1 = new String[4];
final String[] array2 = array1;
```