# Change URL dynamically Android studio

Tags: java, android, terminal, android-testing

I have some tests set up that I need to run from Terminal, however I need to be able to choose which URL I want to point to for my API calls instead of live. Is there a way I can do this in terminal?

At the moment I have a string in my `Constants.java` file that I point to different ones, but I need to do it from terminal apparently! So my string is `private static String BASE_URL = "http://www.website.com/"` this is the string I want to change in terminal.

I've written the following but it doesn't appear to ask me to input anything.

```
    @Before
    public void setURLForAPICalls() {
        Scanner url_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the server you wish to test against: ");
        Constants.BASE_URL = url_input.next();
}
```

Even if it's a case of setting it up in a `@Before` test method or something? I've been trying to figure this out for days and starting to think it's impossible to do...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by _apparently_? It would be helpful if you post your code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: You can pass in arguments to the main method and parse by those. Relevant question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java

Comment: @px06 by apparently, I do aha. I have no code to post coz I have no idea how to do it!

Comment: You can edit your post and include code in it.

Comment: @px06 I've put a bit in, that's what I need to change via terminal but I have no idea how!

Comment: You cannot change the value of `final` members... See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-final-keyword-works

Comment: You should add some code. Not all of it, just the important part

Comment: @px06 @Rafael Cardoso I've added some code of what I think should work but when I run `./gradlew test it still doesn't ask me to enter a url to use for my tests :( what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From your question you have stated that in `Constants.java` you have the following statement:

```
private static String BASE_URL = "http://www.website.com/";
```

When you test, you're trying to change this `BASE_URL`, which you cannot do. Not only is it a `private` member or `Constants` but it's also a `final` member, which means the value of it cannot be changed.

What you can do is create instantiate `Constants` when your app runs and you can specify it to be either a `TEST` or a `RELEASE` version.

Something like the following may be sufficient:

```
public enum RUN_TYPE {
    TEST, 
    RELEASE;
}
```

You can modify your `Constants` class to be something like the following:

```
public class Constants {

    private static final instance = new Constants();

    private RUN_TYPE type;

    private String BASE_URL;

    // More urls here

    private Constants(){

    }

    public void setRunType(RUN_TYPE type){
        this.type = type;
        if(type == RUN_TYPE.RELEASE){
            BASE_URL = "http://release.api/endpoints";
        } else if(type == RUN_TYPE.TEST){
            BASE_URL = "http://test.api/endpoints";
        }
    }

    public String getBaseUrl(){
        return BASE_URL;
    }

    public static Constants getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    // More getters here

}
```

This is a singleton class that will contain the values needed as you specify.

In release mode you can call:

```
Constants.getInstance().setRunType(RUN_TYPE.RELEASE);
```

And while testing you can do something like:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class TestSomething {


    @BeforeClass
    public static void runOnce(){
        Constants.getInstance().setRunType(RUN_TYPE.TEST);
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne(){
        // tests
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters while executing a test through a CLI.

For example, if you want to pass the URL while executing the tests, you can do something like:

```
am instrument -w -r -e URL "http://www.google.com" -e debug false -e class com.example.android.TestClassName com.example.android.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

To fetch the value of the same in your tests, you can use:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getArguments().getString("URL")
```

For more information, you can read about `-e` here: [Test from the Command Line](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html)