# Rename logger at runtime based on user input

Tags: java

As the title says, I have a Logger object *logger*, in a class *classname* the definition of *classname* contains a vararg String *v*. If *v* does exist, *logger* should be named that, else it should have a default. How should I do this? My code:

```
final Logger logger=null;
    if(globalLogger!=null){
        logger.getLogger(globalLogger);
    }
    else{
      logger.getLogger(ImportThread.class.getName());
    }
```

This returns:**The static method getLogger(String) should be accessed in a static way**.
Is this possible? If not, how should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

access it statically means you call it as method of the class:

```
Logger logger=null;

if(globalLogger!=null){
    logger = Logger.getLogger(globalLogger);
} else{
  logger = Logger.getLogger(ImportThread.class.getName());
}
```

In your code, you did not use what `Logger.getLogger()` returned, I changed to an assignment; with this code you cannot make it final, because you cannot reassign a final variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify which Logger class you are using. From the current info it seems to me the `Logger logger` variable should be static

```
static final Logger logger=null;
```

Note sure about the rest of the code but this should at least fix the "should be accessed in a static way" issue

Comment: This change gives an **Only one final allowed** error.

Comment: you should not declare it as final, assign it null and then try to change the reference. Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15655012/1304575) and API docs on more info on the final keyword

Comment: Ok, but it also say only final allowed.

Comment: Please post the complete error message. No way for anyone to help unless they know what is happening.

Comment: That went away, but the original error message: file: 'The static method getLogger(String) from the type Logger should be accessed in a static way' is still here