# uncompilable source code - variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, higher-order-functions

I am currently trying to get a high order function working, but it keeps telling me that f may not have been defined. My understanding is that it should be defined as it must be given in order to run the method IntApply. Any advice would be appreciated.

```java
package iterators;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class IntApply implements Iterator {

    // The function that will be applied to each input element to make an output element
    private final IntApplyFunction f;

    // The Iterator that this Apply object will get its input from
    private final Iterator<Integer> input;      

    public IntApply(IntApplyFunction f, Iterator<Integer> input) {
        while(input.hasNext()){
            f.apply(input.next());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return input.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        return input.next();
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your code and not a picture of it

Comment: Just a tip, people here will crucify you if you post your code as a pic. People want to be able to copy and paste the code to test it themselves.

Comment: My apologizes, made the changes

Answer (score -1):

You have declared `f` and `input` as `final` you either have to initialize them in your constructor/constructors or remove the final keyword.

In this particular case, since your receiving the variable as an argument you can assign it to the object variable field.

```java
public IntApply(IntApplyFunction f, Iterator<Integer> input) {
    this.f = f;
    this.input = input;
    // rest of the constructor
}
```

Here you can see what is the `final` keyword.
[How does the "final" keyword in Java work? (I can still modify an object.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-does-the-final-keyword-in-java-work-i-can-still-modify-an-object)

Comment: I tried removing the final and still have the same error.

Also I tried including the statement this.f = f; in the constructor but that didn't fix it either. Thank you for the advice though.

Comment: What type is f in "private final IntApplyFunction f;"   What is IntApplyFunction?

Comment: From my understanding it is a higher order function, which is to say an unspecified function that can be used by iterators change the data based off what function is passed into it.

Comment: Well no matter what type f is, initializing `this.f` and `this.input` should solve the problem. Removing final is the other solution. I edited the answer because I missed in the first place the variable `input`.

Comment: I got it working. I didn't actually have to remove the final, I just needed the two constructors. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yep, here's what I have working.

  public IntApply(IntApplyFunction f, Iterator<Integer> input) {
                    this.f = f;
                    this.input = input;
                    while(input.hasNext()){
                        f.apply(input.next());
                    }
  }

Comment: Yeap, it was either that or removing the final, not both.