# Errors with simple String object in Java

Tags: java, string, declaration, declare

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String final = new String("");
        final = "sample";
        System.out.println(final);
    }
}
```

Apparently, the compiler shows me the following errors:

```
Test.java:5: error: not a statement
    String final = new String("");
    ^
Test.java:5: error: ';' expected
    String final = new String("");
          ^
Test.java:5: error: illegal start of type
    String final = new String("");
                 ^
Test.java:6: error: illegal start of type
    final = "sample";
          ^
Test.java:7: error: illegal start of expression
    System.out.println(final);
                       ^
Test.java:7: error: illegal start of type
    System.out.println(final);
                            ^
```

I've tried replacing `String final = new String("");` with `String final;` but the compiler is still showing these errors. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: `final` is a reserved keyword in java. You can't use it as variable name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`final` is the [reserved Java keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). You can't use it as a variable name. Read more about the [naming of variables in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). Do this:

```
String string = new String("");
string = "sample";
System.out.println(string);
```

However, this is possible, since it still respects the rule to assign the value once:

```
final String string;
string = "sample";
System.out.println(string);
```

On the other hand, if you mean to make String `final`, not as a variable name, but as characteristics, you have to place it to the left side of String definition. However, the second line would not compile because you can't modify the variable marked as `final`.

```
final String string = new String("");
string = "sample";                // not possible, string already has a value
System.out.println(string);
```

The behavior of variable which is `final` is that you can initialize it only once. Read more at [How does the “final” keyword in Java work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15655012/3764965)

Answer (score 1):

`final` is a keyword *(reserved word)* in `java`. You can't use keywords as a variable name. Try some another name.

Try this code :-

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String Final = new String("");
    Final = "sample";                 // final is keyword so use Final or some other names
    System.out.println(Final);
   }
 }
```

**Output :-**

```
sample
```

Answer (score 0):

final is a reserved keyword in Java. Rename the varriable.