# Why can I re-assign a new value to a final variable in Android AIDE?

Tags: java, android, final, aide-ide

How this is possible? How am I able to change variables marked as final?

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int NUM;

        NUM = 22;
        NUM = 33;

        System.out.println(NUM);
    }

}
```

I was using AIDE app in Android... it compiled successfully and printed `33`.

Comment: You can't (due to my 5 seconds Google research).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "final" keyword in Java work? (I can still modify an object.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-does-the-final-keyword-in-java-work-i-can-still-modify-an-object)

Comment: Looks like I can... Compile this code...

Comment: Tried your code and getting a compile error `The final local variable NUM may already have been assigned` as expected.

Comment: @Amit That's more like initialization than changing.

Comment: A final variable once declared can't be re assigned a new value

Comment: I was using AIDE app in android... it complied successful and showed me 33...

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in AIDE app... That's why it compiled...

Comment: I've updated your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I have successfully reproduced this on a oneplus 5 with AIDE v3.2.180516 on Android 8.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can do this, it is a bug in the AIDE app.  You should report it to the developers.  A JLS compliant implementation of Java does not allow reassignment of `final` variables (like this).

If you want to give them a JLS specification reference to support your bug report:

> [JLS 4.12.4 `final` variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)
>
> A variable can be declared final. A final variable may only be assigned to once. It is a compile-time error if a final variable is assigned to unless it is definitely unassigned immediately prior to the assignment ([§16 (Definite Assignment)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-16.html)).