# Is there a way to change final variables, after they have been assigned?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, final

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OnlineShop {

  public static void main (String[]args) {

    final double subAmmount;

    subAmmount = subAmmount + Array[i];
}
```

**The error:**

`The final local variable subAmmount may have already been assigned`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "final" keyword in Java work? (I can still modify an object.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-does-the-final-keyword-in-java-work-i-can-still-modify-an-object)

Comment: The actual error this code gives is `variable subAmmount might not have been initialized`.

Comment: *Not* being able to do that is the point of `final`.

Answer (score 0):

"subAmmount" has not been initialized/set  yet, so you cannot add subAmmount to itself, since it is not equal to anything.

Answer (score -1):

Because `subAmount` is not declared as `static`, it must be initialized at the time of declaration. So you should have something like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OnlineShop {

  public static void main (String[]args) {

    final double subAmmount = Array[i]; // Assuming Array[i] is defined somewhere
}
```

If you'd like to do declaration followed by initialization, you'd do:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OnlineShop {

  static final double subAmmount;

  public static void main (String[]args) {

    subAmmount = Array[i]; // Assuming Array[i] is defined somewhere
}
```

Checkout this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/final-keyword-java/) for more nuances on the `final` keyword