# Can't change the value of integer variable

Tags: java, android

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        TextSwitcher textSwitcherage, textSwitcherGender;
        Button nextButton, previousButton, nextButton2, previousButton2;
        String[] age = {"U-4","Kid","Teen","Adult","Old"};
        String[] gender = {"Male","Female","Other"};
        TextView textView;
        Typeface typeface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        defVars();
    }

    public void defVars()
    {
        textSwitcherGender = findViewById(R.id.textSwitcherGender);
        textSwitcherage = findViewById(R.id.textSwitcherage);
        nextButton = findViewById(R.id.nextButton1);
        nextButton2 = findViewById(R.id.nextButton2);
        previousButton = findViewById(R.id.previousButton1);
        previousButton2 = findViewById(R.id.previousButton2);
        typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.lettersforlearners);

        nextAndPreviousButtons(nextButton,previousButton,textSwitcherage,age,0);
        nextAndPreviousButtons(nextButton2, previousButton2, textSwitcherGender, gender,0);
    }

    public void nextAndPreviousButtons(Button buttonNext, Button buttonPrevious, final TextSwitcher textSwitcher, final String[] data, final Integer stringIndex)
    {
        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(stringIndex == data.length - 1)
                {
                    stringIndex = 0;
                    textSwitcher.setText(data[stringIndex]);
                }
                else
                {
                    textSwitcher.setText(data[++stringIndex]);
                }
            }
        });

        buttonPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(stringIndex==0)
                {
                    stringIndex = data.length-1;
                    textSwitcher.setText(data[stringIndex]);
                }
                else
                {
                    textSwitcher.setText(data[--stringIndex]);
                }
            }
        });

        textSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
            @Override
            public View makeView() {
                textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                textView.setTypeface(typeface);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                textView.setTextSize(40);
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                return textView;
            }
        });

        textSwitcher.setText(data[stringIndex]);

    }
}
```

I have an error:

> "error: cannot assign a value to final variable stringIndex"

I set the `stringIndex` final but still got that problem. I don't know. Am i have to define Integer variables for stringIndex? Or should I delete the stringIndex final? I need to define separate stringIndex variables for each function

Comment: It is not possible to assign a new value to a final variable (also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15655032/4295944)

Answer (score 0):

if you declare `final Integer stringIndex...` then you are done! that is the idea and meaning of the reserved word final... is an object you cannot re assign after...

```
public void nextAndPreviousButtons(Button buttonNext, Button buttonPrevious, 
   final TextSwitcher textSwitcher, final String[] data, Integer stringIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to modify `stringIndex`

```
    public void nextAndPreviousButtons(Button buttonNext, Button buttonPrevious, final TextSwitcher textSwitcher, final String[] data, final Integer stringIndex)
    {
        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(stringIndex == data.length - 1)
                {
                    textSwitcher.setText(data[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    textSwitcher.setText(data[stringIndex+1]);
                }
            }
        });

        buttonPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(stringIndex==0)
                {
                    textSwitcher.setText(data[data.length-1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    textSwitcher.setText(data[stringIndex-1]);
                }
            }
        });

        textSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
            @Override
            public View makeView() {
                textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                textView.setTypeface(typeface);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                textView.setTextSize(40);
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                return textView;
            }
        });

        textSwitcher.setText(data[stringIndex]);
```

Comment: sir but i still have problem at else blocks: error: cannot assign a value to final variable stringIndex textSwitcher.setText(data[++stringIndex]);