# can't use method removeAll in Java list

Tags: java, arraylist, removeall

I have  a list of integers 1,2,3,4 in one list, called a1temp and want to use the items in GA to delete the same items in a1temp, using **a1temp.removeAll(GA);**

Basically,
Got a list of items in list A
want to remove same items in list B

So I've got my code

I'd appreciate any help possible. thanks in advance

Obviously, importing couple of things, import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;

```
class R{

List<Integer> GA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> a1temp = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
int a1 = 0;
int a2 = 0;
int a3 = 0;
int a4 = 0;
```

// if a1 is not 0 (has another value) & it's not already in GA will check it's value and add it to GA.

```
public void checkGA() {
     if (a1 != 0) {
           if (!GA.contains(a1)) {
               GA.add(a1);
               }}}
```

// remove items from listA with items from listB.

```
public void placeGA() {

        // Check if GA has some value.
        if (GA.size() > 0) {
            try {
               //Here is where the problem appears.
               // "a1temp list" should be getting the items removed  
               // when "a1temp" has same items as "GA list"
                a1temp.removeAll(GA);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Can't delete");
}}}
```

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        R r1 = new R();
        r1.a1 = 4;
        r1.a2 = 3;
        r1.a3 = 2;

        // We add items from a1, a2 & a3 to GA list
        r1.checkGA();
        System.out.println("Show GA");
        // Shows current items in GA list
        System.out.println(r1.GA);
```

console:

Show GA

[4, 3, 2]

```
System.out.println("show a1temp);
// defined before a1temp = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
System.out.println(r1.a1temp);
```

console:

Show a1temp

[1, 2, 3, 4]

```
// try to delete items 2, 3, 4.
r1.placeGA();
}
```

console
Can't delete.

---

error showed:
Error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:142)
at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableCollection.removeAll(ImmutableCollections.java:151)
at R.placeGA(Main.java:124)
at Main.main(Main.java:255)

So I've tried deleting the items 2, 3, 4 from a1temp, so it would show only the item 1 on the list.

Can anyone tell my why is not working?

Thanks in advance. Its my first post.

Tried to remove items 2, 3, 4 from one list, but getting an error.

Comment: You should print out the exception stacktrace, to whats going on

Comment: BTW: Do not catch the base class `Exception`. Only catch subclasses that you expect

Comment: From [the documentation of `List::of` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of()): "*Returns an unmodifiable list containing zero elements. See [Unmodifiable Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) for details.*"

Comment: First of all, just in case I haven't said before, Im a newbie and sorry for any confusion or "stupid" question asked :)
So I understand that static is unmodifiable, but the items are showed and the class nor method are static.

Comment: I'm confused. You show output, so your code seems to compile. But then you mention a compiler error. Which is it?

Comment: "*So I understand that static is unmodifiable, but the items are showed and the class nor method are static.*" - This is not correct. I suspect you are confusing `static` with `final`. Using `List.of(...)` literally returns a map that cannot be modified (no `add(...)`. `addAll(...)`, `remove(...)`, `removeAll(...)`, ...).

Comment: Errors:
Error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:142)
 at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableCollection.removeAll(ImmutableCollections.java:151)
 at R.placeGA(Main.java:124)
 at Main.main(Main.java:255)

Comment: I recommend reading about `static` (e.g. over at [`oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)) and `final` (e.g. in [this `stackoverflow.com` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-does-the-final-keyword-in-java-work-i-can-still-modify-an-object)).

Comment: I'm still reading the link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html
but dont want to appear rude not answering :D
Thanks for the info. Will get back to you as soon as the baby allows me to finish reading and I understand & learn a little bit more

Comment: @Turing85 It returns a List, not a Map.

Comment: @DavidConrad oh true :) typo, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the JavaDoc for List

**Unmodifiable Lists**

The `List.of` and `List.copyOf` static factory methods provide a convenient way to create unmodifiable lists. The List instances created by these methods have the following characteristics:

- They are [*unmodifiable*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#unmodifiable). Elements cannot be added, removed, or replaced. Calling any mutator method on the List will always cause UnsupportedOperationException to be thrown. However, if the contained elements are themselves mutable, this may cause the List's contents to appear to change.
- They disallow null elements. Attempts to create them with null elements result in NullPointerException.
- They are serializable if all elements are serializable.
- The order of elements in the list is the same as the order of the provided arguments, or of the elements in the provided array.
- The lists and their subList views implement the RandomAccess interface.
- They are value-based. Programmers should treat instances that are equal as interchangeable and should not use them for synchronization, or unpredictable behavior may occur. For example, in a future release, synchronization may fail. Callers should make no assumptions about the identity of the returned instances. Factories are free to create new instances or reuse existing ones.
- They are serialized as specified on the Serialized Form page.

So you need to change it as follows:

```
List<Integer> a1temp = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Answer (score 2):

[List.of](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)) creates an immutable list, hence UnsupportedOpration on `removeAll`.

One simple way would be to use the `ArrayList` constructor that takes another list as an argument:

```
List<Integer> a1temp = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4));
```