# What is this variable public final static

Tags: java, variables

I am a beginner in Java Programmer and do not understand what is this variable: `public final static int ID = 8;` please tell me a definition or example code. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried searching on the web for those keywords?

Comment: It's a 'magic number' !!! (really).

Comment: @squiguy yes, but I did not find a clear definition.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677670/when-exactly-are-we-supposed-to-use-public-static-final-string

Comment: It's essentially a constant to your class.

Answer (score 2):

`public` - Any object can see it, even objects that use your code as a library.

`final` - its value will never change.

`static` - however many objects of this class you create, there will be only one.

`int` - it is a 32-bit integer.

`ID` - it can be referred to by this name.

`=` - it is immediately assigned the value.

`8` - it will have the value 8 (decimal).

This form is commonly used for constant values. The compiler will often replace every access to it with its constant value instead.

Answer (score 0):

`public` means that it can be accessed from other classes

`final` means it cannot be reinitialized i.e its value can't be changed after initialization.

`static` means that all `instances` of the class use the same exact field (unlike non-static fields where each instance has their own version of the field). `static` fields are described as being ['class variables'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) Similarly, non-static fields are called 'instance variables'

Comment: That's not what static means.....

Comment: What do you mean it can not be changed?

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated answer

Comment: Thanks Epicblood, rolfl, daniellarsson :D

Answer (score -2):

`public` means it accessible by any other class outside of that one.

`final` means once the variable is declared it cannot be changed.

`static` means the variable can be accessed from any method within the class.

`int` is a primitive data type declaration.

These are all basic concepts of Java OOP, so I'd recommend reading about it a little.

Declaring Variables: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Comment: That's not what static means

Comment: Static means that the variable is not associated with an instance but with the class itself.

Comment: Yeah sometimes people rush in a bit for free reps but instead get a kickback

Comment: Static means something different from final I know, but if you declare a static variable outside of any method, it doesn't make that much of a difference for its usage. It just means that the variable belongs to the class not any particular method or constructor.

Comment: @Wold - you are wrong on this one, and the subtle difference is significant: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class

Comment: I kind of there is a HUGE difference though..

Comment: @rolfl I admit my misunderstanding of the implications of a static variable. I just thought that it seemed intuitive that a variable both final and static would not exist only once.