# What's the rationale for using static final Strings for SQL statement strings?

Tags: java, constants

It seems many places incorporate as best practice the use of class constants for SQL strings.

So instead of:

```
String sql = "select * from users";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

It's preferred to do:

```
private static final String SQL_SELECT_USERS = "select * from users";

void someMethod() {
  ...
  PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT_USERS);
  ...
}
```

What are the advantages to the latter? It seems to me it's less readable.

Thanks.

Comment: final variables can not be changed - adds a little bit of safety

Comment: It's also a signal to other developers: don't try to muck about with the value of this.

Comment: Accepted answer here sums it up nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677670/when-exactly-are-we-supposed-to-use-public-static-final-string

Comment: By making it private, no other class can access it. By making it static there is only one instance. By making it final it becomes a constant. Since the query is a constant in either case, it's generally considered best practice to treat it as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `final` variable cannot be changed, by mistake or otherwise.  Declaring the statement string as `final` makes sure to avoid this bug:

```
String s = "select * from users";

// many lines of code
s = "temp";
// do something with s
// many lines of code
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

No matter how many lines of code you add after declaring `s`, if `s` is `final` the compiler will tell you when some code attempts to clobber it with a new value.

If you always do the prepared statement immediately after the variable, then simple proximity will help you avoid this error.  Also, your actual example used a better name (`sql` rather than just `s`).  But still, you never know who will edit your code after you write it.

Any time you can use a feature of the language to get the compiler to help you, you should do it.  In this case, the `final` declaration lets the compiler protect you from someone clobbering your pre-defined string.  Admittedly in this specific example the benefit seems pretty small, but in general constant things should be declared `final` and I don't see any reason to break that rule for this case.

As for declaring it `private`, that is just typical data hiding.  If this string isn't part of the "interface" to this class, it should be private; by default, make everything private, and only make the interface stuff public.

EDIT: One more point worth considering.  If you have a literal string that contains SQL, and you make some mistake when writing the SQL, the compiler cannot help you.  `"selct * from users"` is a perfectly valid string; the Java compiler doesn't know it's an SQL error, so you find out at runtime.

You can make constants that are SQL fragments, and put them together with string concatenation.  The great part about this is that if you misspell something, now you likely have a compiler error.

```
private final String SELECT_STAR_FROM = "select * from ";
private final String USERS_TABLE = "users";

// many lines of code
PreparedStatement stmt0 = conn.prepareStatement(SELECT_STAR_FROM + USERS_TABLE);

// this line would fail at run time
PreparedStatement stmt1 = conn.prepareStatement("selct * from users");

// this line fails at compile time and the compiler points you at it
PreparedStatement stmt0 = conn.prepareStatement(SELCT_STAR_FROM + USERS_TABLE);
```

When you do JNI programming you need to specify function signatures with cryptic codes.  I made a bunch of constants and my JNI programs concatenate the constants together to build up the function signatures.  This is C code, not Java, but it illustrates the same idea as the above.

```
#define JSIG_CONSTRUCTOR "<init>"
```

If I made a typo and wrote `"<intt>"` for a constructor, the C compiler couldn't help me; it would be a runtime error (JNI would fail to find the constructor). But if I use `JSIG_CONSTRUCTOR` in my code, if I make a typo, the compiler will tell me.

Comment: The static final is no more secure from accidental modification than coding `conn.prepareStatement("select * from users");`.  Probably less so, especially when the program is modified and `SQL_SELECT_USERS` is changed to suit the needs of one use, without regard to the needs of others.

Comment: @HotLicks As soon as you use a given string more than once, it becomes a win to make a constant and use the constant.  And there can be value in putting all the SQL statements together as a set of constants so it's easier to review them all for correctness (only need to look in one spot).  Also, you just reminded me of one more point, which I will edit into the answer.

Comment: A win how?  Not in performance.  And your new "advantage" is questionable, given the added obfuscation.  Better to use a toolkit that relieves you entirely from writing SQL.

Comment: A win in the sense that if you need to run the exact same SQL in multiple places, you only need to write it and/or change it in a single place.  This is obvious.  Clearly you disagree with me on some things, but I don't think you need to put scare quotes around advantage.  If you think the obfuscation is a disadvantage that more than outweighs the gain of catching a typo at compile time rather than run time, then use literals not constants.  As for using a toolkit, I probably agree; I prefer to use an ORM rather than write SQL directly.  But the point is general; consider my JNI example.

Comment: @steveha , In case of Spring Boot Project, Where I am using Spring JDBC template , does the above holds true.. ?

Answer (score 5):

If it is a short text and it is used only in one place then there is no need to make it a field. In your case it could be this

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from users");
```

You can find a lot of this kind of coding style in JDK source, like this one

```
    if (is == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("InputStream cannot be null");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are really two issues at play here. The first is declaring the variable `final`; this provides a little bit of safety (you can't accidentally modify it later on, introducing a potentially intermittent runtime bug), and it indicates to anyone reading the code that the value is meant to be a constant.

Pulling the string out into a constant field (`static final`) is a bit more efficient and helps collect the important values in the class in one place. If the query statement is buried in `someMethod()`, it's harder to find and can't be reused between methods. By using class-level constants instead of "magic values", IDEs and Javadoc can identify their role, and developers needing to change the code later can find them more easily.

Comment: Actually, a static final and a string literal are essentially the same thing (the compiler converts the former to the latter) and should have identical efficiency.  And if the static were not final it would be less efficient to access than the string literal.

Comment: A `static final` and string literal are, but just a `final` variable or field isn't necessarily, and I was trying to answer more generally (only `String` objects are interned).

Comment: But the point is that the static final is no more "secure", nor is it faster, than simply coding the string literal at the point of use.  The reason for using a more global value is to allow the string to be coded only once, vs being re-coded several places.  (The number of strings would be the same, since literals are always interned.)

Answer (score 2):

This is just one example of a very old (and very reasonable) programming practice of using **constants** instead of **literals**, e.g. the `SQL_SELECT_USERS` variable, instead of the `"select * from users"` literal string.

A similar approach is applicable (and advisable) for using numbers (e.g., `BUFFER_SIZE` instead of 4096) or any other type of value that is **constant** throughout the code of a class (or more than one classes). Constants (i.e., variables that are initialized only once and never change) in `Java` are declared using the `final` keyword.

Such is not a "less readable" strategy, either. On the contrary, if the name of the constant is intuitive, it makes much more sense than having the literal used in its place. Most importantly, after the constant is declared, it can be used as many times as necessary in the code and if, later on, its value needs to be changed (a very common case, indeed), the (whatever) change only needs to happen in one place (that of the declaration of the constant), instead of having to search through classes to make all the changes.

For constants that represent numbers, using the actual number instead of a single constant is called using a **magic number** in the code. That is not advisable because, after a while, it is difficult to remember why a value is defined as such. A constant with an intuitive name solves that problem.

So, using constants instead of literals is a strongly advisable programming habit to adopt.

Comment: Using constants makes a lot of sense for "magic numbers", but often just obfuscates things when used for stuff like SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

The static final is no more "secure", nor is it faster, than simply coding the string literal at the point of use.  (The number of strings would be the same, since literals are always interned, and the static final gets converted to a literal by the compiler anyway.)

The reason for using a more global value is to allow the string to be coded only once, vs being re-coded several places, and to collect all of the SQL string definitions in one location.  This can be a good idea or a bad one, depending on circumstances (and the abilities of the programmer).  One problem is that it can greatly obfuscate the code.  Another is that if the value is defined in another class it must be class-prefixed, leading to some long names  (If it's not defined globally like this then the advantage of coding only once is apt to be lost.)

It should be noted that it's foolishness to use this technique to "improve security", and then fail to use prepared statements for operations using externally-provided data values.